# Opening Google calendar from Flutter app (Deep Linking)

Tags: flutter, google-calendar-api, flutter-dependencies, deep-linking

I want to open Google calendar app more specifically the create event page in the app from my another flutter app.

I am using the URL launcher package but it opens the app in chrome
What change should I make in the URL so that the add event page opens directly in the google calendar app.

Currently my URL looks like below

> https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/eventedit?dates=20210226T033000/20210226T040000&ctz=Asia/Calcutta&location&text=Blawsome:+A+Crystal+Alchemy+Healing+Meditation&details=Parth+Pitroda

My code for that part is as below

```
if (await canLaunchUrl(Uri.parse('https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/eventedit?dates=20210226T033000/20210226T040000&ctz=Asia/Calcutta&location&text=Blawsome:+A+Crystal+Alchemy+Healing+Meditation&details=Parth+Pitroda'))) {
await launchUrl(
            Uri.parse('https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/eventedit?dates=20210226T033000/20210226T040000&ctz=Asia/Calcutta&location&text=Blawsome:+A+Crystal+Alchemy+Healing+Meditation&details=Parth+Pitroda'),
          mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
} else {
    throw 'Could not launch URL';
}
```

Comment: What kind of device is this app running on?

Comment: Its running Android.

Answer (score 0):

rathe than using a HTTP request, you could use `googleapis` package from https://pub.dev which has inbuilt methods to create `Google Calender` events directly within the `Calender` app.

Check [package](https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis) and [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/create-events#javascript) here.

Happy coding!

Comment: Ya, I had done that previously but I don't want to use the googleapis due to certain constraints hence was looking for a workaround.

Comment: I dont think I can help anymore. I've noticed that if a `Dynamic Link (from Firebase)`, lets say is configured, when it's opened, it automatically redirects to the linked app. So I'd expect such auto redirect in case of `Google Calendar` too, but it doesn't happen. I'd say keep looking for solutions, else this package should be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with the same problem and after trying many (many) things, I've finally got it working using the package `url_launcher` and using this as the URL `content://com.android.calendar/events/75` so a simple push button would look like this

```
    final Uri url = Uri.parse('content://com.android.calendar/events/75');
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () async {
        await launchUrl(url);
      },
      child: const Text('Click Here'),
    );
```

Comment: Replace 75 with the event id that you wish to open

Comment: I used this reference to help.  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider#intents

Comment: As you want to edit, I also had some success with the package `android_intent ` which might be more suitable for edit intents 
      ```onPressed: () {AndroidIntent intent = const AndroidIntent(action: 'action_view', data: 'content://com.android.calendar',);
        intent.launch();},```